# Prove that {(-1)^n} is not a Cauchy Sequence by using the definition.

Tags: analysis

I need to use the definition of a Cauchy Sequence to prove that {$(-1)^n$} is not a Cauchy sequence.
I believe I have the main idea down by am lacking a part in my reasoning.

Proof:

For sake of contradiction assume that {$(-1)^n$} is a cauchy sequence. Take $\epsilon =1$. Then there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all m,n $\geq N$ $\Rightarrow |(-1)^m -(-1)^n|$. Let m= N and n = N+1.
Then, $|(-1)^m -(-1)^n| = |(-1)^N-(-1)^{N+1}| = |1-(-1)^{N+1}|$.

This is where I am stuck. I am not sure how to properly show that $(-1)^{N+1}$ reduces down to (-1) which give us |1-(-1)| = 2 >1 thus it is not a cauchy sequence.

Comment: Note $|(-1)^N-(-1)^{N+1}|=|2(-1)^N|=2$.

Comment: There is a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$ we have $|(-1)^m-(-1)^n|<\epsilon=1$. In particular, we can find $m,n$ such that $|(-1)^m-(-1)^n|=2$, a contradiction

Comment: The point is that $(-1)^N$ and $(-1)^{N+1}$ will have one of them (*maybe the first, but maybe the second instead*) evaluate to $1$ and the other to $-1$.  We do not know ahead of time which it is unless we decide whether $N$ is even or odd.  If you want to avoid this here... note that $|(-1)^N-(-1)^{N+1}| = |(-1)^N|\cdot |1 - (-1)^1|$ by factoring out $(-1)^N$ from both the first and second terms.

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t necessarily true that $(-1)^N=1$: that is the case if and only if $N$ is even. You could divide the argument into two cases, one for even $N$ and one for odd $N$, but it’s neater simply to factor out $(-1)^N$:

$$\left|(-1)^N-(-1)^{N+1}\right|=\left|(-1)^N\right|\cdot|1-(-1)|=1\cdot 2=2\,.$$

If you choose to use cases, when $N=2m$ is even you have $$(-1)^N=(-1)^{2m}=\big((-1)^2\big)^m=1^m=1$$ and $$(-1)^{N+1}=(-1)^N(-1)=(1)(-1)=-1\,,$$

and when $N=2m+1$ is odd you have

$$(-1)^N=(-1)^{2m+1}=(-1)^{2m}(-1)=(1)(-1)=-1$$

and

$$(-1)^{N+1}=(-1)^N(-1)=(-1)(-1)=1\,.$$